# Code Data iCloud error

Tags: ios, icloud

I am working on adding iCloud support to a Core Data app based on ios 5.  I can install the app just fine on the first device and the data is uploaded to iCloud.  When I try to install the app on the second device for testing, I get this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil key'

Here is my relevant iCloud code:

// ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you MUST change this variable:
        NSString *iCloudEnabledAppID = @"com.strikelabs.iXercise";

```
    // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you should change this variable:        
    NSString *dataFileName = @"Xercise.sqlite";

    // ** Note: For basic usage you shouldn't need to change anything else

    NSString *iCloudDataDirectoryName = @"Data";
    NSString *iCloudLogsDirectoryName = @"Logs";
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];        
    NSURL *localStore = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];

    NSURL *iCloud = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

    if (iCloud) {

        NSLog(@"iCloud is working");

        NSURL *iCloudLogsPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudLogsDirectoryName]];

        NSLog(@"iCloudEnabledAppID = %@",iCloudEnabledAppID);
        NSLog(@"dataFileName = %@", dataFileName); 
        NSLog(@"iCloudDataDirectoryName = %@", iCloudDataDirectoryName);
        NSLog(@"iCloudLogsDirectoryName = %@", iCloudLogsDirectoryName);  
        NSLog(@"iCloud = %@", iCloud);
        NSLog(@"iCloudLogsPath = %@", iCloudLogsPath);

        if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]] == NO) {
            NSError *fileSystemError;
            [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName] 
                   withIntermediateDirectories:YES 
                                    attributes:nil 
                                         error:&fileSystemError];
            if(fileSystemError != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error creating database directory %@", fileSystemError);
            }
        }

        NSString *iCloudData = [[[iCloud path] 
                                 stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName] 
                                stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];

        NSLog(@"iCloudData = %@", iCloudData);

        NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
        [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];
        [options setObject:iCloudEnabledAppID            forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
        [options setObject:iCloudLogsPath                forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey];

        [psc lock];

        [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                          configuration:nil 
                                    URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:iCloudData] 
                                options:options 
                                  error:nil];

        [psc unlock];
```

The error occurs during the addPersistentStoreWithType as far as I can tell.  I am testing on an iPhone 4S and iPad 2.  The error always occurs on the second device no matter which order I install the app.

Any help would be appreciated!

It appears the error occurs anytime there is an iCloud entity for my program and the program is installed on a device.

EDIT:  Looks like this is fixed.  You must have .nosync as a suffix to the local storage location for Core Data.

Comment: So the name of the store should be @"Xercise.sqlite.nosync"?